# Generating unique code depending on the variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, algorithm

I already have an automatic code generator on my system that I am using.

This code generator combines the string received as a parameter and the numerical value in the database by one, and returns them.

```
public async Task<APIResult> AutoCodeGenerate(string screenCode)
        {

            AutoCode entity = await uow.Repository<AutoCode>().Get().
                FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ScreenCode == screenCode);

            if (entity != null)
            {
                int lastCodeNumber = ++entity.LastCodeNumber;
                var code = String.Format(entity.CodeFormat, lastCodeNumber);

                entity.LastCodeNumber = lastCodeNumber;

                await uow.SaveChangesAsync();

                return new APIResult { Data = code, Message = null };
            }
            else
            {
                return new APIResult { Data = null, Message = null };

            }
        }
```

Now what I want to do is, besides the string that comes as a parameter, there is data that I have captured from the context. Now the automatically generated code should be unique and incremental according to this data.

For example:

AutoCodeGenerator ("EXP") and context data is: "01" this method should return 01-EXP-001.

AutoCodeGenerator ("EXP") and context data is: "02" this method should return 02-EXP-001.

Also AutoCode table is:

```
public class AutoCode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Fixed screen codes
    /// <see cref="Const.ScreenCodes"/>
    /// </summary>
    [Column(TypeName = "char(5)")]
    public string ScreenCode { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Sample code format = "TC-{0}-RS"
    /// </summary>
    [Required, MaxLength(20)]
    public string CodeFormat { get; set; }
    public int LastCodeNumber { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: my question is, I want it to generate unique code according to the data from context.

Comment: This has a concurrency issue. If two people run this at the same time, they'll get the same `lastCodeNumber`

Comment: How can I solve this :/